# Inside docker container grpc client receives neither response nor status

Tags: python-3.x, docker, grpc

In my project I have a grpc communication between two microservices inside Docker container's. When the client is local and the server is in a container, the client places a request to the server and receives a response. When I put the client inside one container and the server inside another, the client makes an request and neither receives the response nor a status.

this is my client:

```
class RoomClient:
    def __init__(self, host='', port=50051):
        conn_str = '{}:{}'.format(host, port)
        self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(conn_str)
        self.stub = booking_pb2_grpc.BookingStub(self.channel)

    # Login call this method
    def rpc_run_get_all(self, request):
        number = booking_pb2.AddRequest(value=request)
        response = self.stub.sendAll(number)
        return response
```

my server:

```
class BookingServicer(booking_pb2_grpc.BookingServicer):

    def sendAll(self, request, context):
        response = booking_pb2.AddReply()
        #response.value = send_all(request.value)
        print ("chegou")
        response.value = str(json_util.dumps({'response': "hello"}))
        return response


def serve():

    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

    booking_pb2_grpc.add_BookingServicer_to_server(BookingServicer(), server)

    print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(86400)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  serve()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the hostname or IP of your server. Use `docker inspect <containerid>` to get the container IP if both containers are running on the same host or put them in the same network and use a dns record for discovery.

This is the layer below GRPC, so any network debugging step will help you here.

Comment: Thanks for replay! I already solve. I used a docker network, I ran the two containers on this network. And in the host address I put the name of the container that was the server.